# What is the logic behind UIView's frame origin and size being read-only

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I know that if you want to resize a `UIView` you have to do it like so:

```
CGRect frame = view.frame;
frame.size.height -= 100;
view.frame = frame;
```

instead of just:

```
view.frame.size.height -= 100;
```

My question is what could be the logic behind this? Is the setter for `frame` doing something extra, like maybe call `setNeedsDisplay` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the reason behind it that the following line

```
view.frame.size.height -= 100;
```

actually does the following 2 things:

1. Calls `[view frame]` method that returns `CGRect` structure - **copy** of what is stored in your view
2. Then it changes the `height` field of the copy - so it does not affect the value of the structure stored in the view

> Is the setter for frame doing something extra, like maybe call
>   setNeedsDisplay ?

Actually yes - view's `frame` property is calculated based on its origin, bounds and transform so setting the frame will also affect its origin and bounds (and depending on view's contentMode may force the view to redraw)

Comment: A key point here is that dot-notation is ambiguous. `view.frame` means `[view frame]`, while `frame.size.height` references a member of a struct. The two are quite different, but have the same syntax, so certain confusion is not surprising.