# How does UIView protect the frame property members?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am curious how does UIView make its .frame property members read-only.
Apparently if I declare and initialise a CGRect for myself, I can use dot notation to modify the struct's members.

But If I try to do that with UIView's frame it doesn't work. 
How might the private implementation look like?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710793/what-is-the-logic-behind-uiviews-frame-origin-and-size-being-read-only

Comment: do you mean,if you set the uiview property as read-only then there is no way you could change the properties of the uiview? Did I get your point? @Earl Grey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you first assign the frame to a local rect variable, you'll find that you can alter that local variable.

```
CGRect frame = view.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;  // this appears to work
```

But that frame is now a local copy, not the actual frame of the view, which you'd need to set back:

```
view.frame = frame; // set the updated struct.
```

You can't do it in a single step like this:

```
view.frame.origin.x = 0; // nope!
```

because you can't alter the member fields without assigning it somewhere first. That's because if you don't assign it, the compiler would only be letting you edit a "temporary" copy of the struct that would immediately disappear. Since that would have no effect on anything, it's not allowed, preventing you from accidentally thinking that it would do something useful.

---

Something that may be confusing here is the notation used to access the property on the view (`.`) which is the same notation as that used to access the member of the struct, but those are in fact doing different things; the dot in `view.frame` is the semantic equivalent of `[view frame]`, an accessor for the frame property that returns a *copy* of a rect structure. (There's no way to operate directly on the version of the frame internal to the view object from outside of the view object.)

Answer (score 2):

Since the frame is a struct (CGRect), it is passed by value, not reference. Because of that, the compiler won't let you make an assignment to a copy of a value that can never be referenced.

If you add a CGRect as a property to your class, it will behave the same way, no special Apple-secret-sauce required.

Answer (score 0):

From the Documentation:

> If you don’t want to allow a property to be changed via a setter method, you can add an attribute to a property declaration to specify that it should be readonly:

```
@property (readonly) UIView *testView;

testView.frame.origin.x=100;  //expresison not assignable
testView.frame.size.height=100;   //expression not assignable
```

Comment: I am talking about .frame property members. Not the .frame property itself. Frame is a struct with two structs inside both having two CGFloats. It's those members that are not asignable.